If i hardcode seed file mock data it works but if i import mock data for seeding from other file it does not work
In my seed.ts file if i import mock user data from other file it raise error.
zohaibamir@174-16-0-44 stt % npx prisma db seed
Environment variables loaded from .env
Running seed command `ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts` ...
Error: Cannot find module '@/utils/server/mock-users'
Require stack:
- /Users/zohaibamir/My Files/DevnTech/stt/prisma/seed.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/zohaibamir/My Files/DevnTech/stt/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zohaibamir/My Files/DevnTech/stt/prisma/seed.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/zohaibamir/My Files/DevnTech/stt/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/zohaibamir/My Files/DevnTech/stt/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/zohaibamir/My Files/DevnTech/stt/prisma/seed.ts' ]
}

An error occurred while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts

Here is my code
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { mockUsers } from "@/utils/server/mock-users";
import { Person, User } from "@/utils/common/person";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function main() {
  const personAData = mockUsers[Person.PersonA];
  const personBData = mockUsers[Person.PersonB];

  if (personAData) {
    await prisma.user.create({
      data: personAData,
    });
  }

  if (personBData) {
    await prisma.user.create({
      data: personBData,
    });
  }
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });

I just want to mention that the path is correct i have checked it.
If i hardcode data like this it works
await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    backgroundImageUrl:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480714378408-67cf0d13bc1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80",
    profilePictureUrl:
      "https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/51efe10de4b025019c37bb06/1566986917034-2MGUTZB04MU2GFSPAC10/London-corporate-headshot-photography.jpg",
    name: "PersonB",
    title: "Full Stack Developer",
    followers: 20000,
    following: 1000,
  },
});

Here is my package.json file
{
  "name": "ssg-next-challenge",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prepare": "husky"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.10.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.37.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "classnames": "^2.5.1",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.378.0",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "sonner": "^1.4.41",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "tw-merge": "^0.0.1-alpha.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.12",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.10",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  }
}


What does your tsconfig.json contain? Please add it to your question.

Ok so i found the solution. I am using page routing in Next.js. So prisma folder is outside the /src folder and my utils folder is inside /src folder. In my tsconfig.json file i have defined the paths like this.
"paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    },

So when in seed file i was trying to access the mockUsers using "@/utils/server/mock-users" path it was actually this path "./src/utils/server/mock-users" and by the location of prisma folder it is trying to access the mock-users at the root level instead of inside src folder. So what i did is just update the import path like this `"../src/utils/server/mock-users"
